# How to organise "sub-applications" with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a pretty large-scale application and would be thankful to get some suggestions from you.
I have an application wrapper in `react-redux` `<Provider>` and it has list of sub-applications.

```
const appState = {
    subApps: [],
};
```

Sub-apps are pretty complicated and it would be convenient to use some of their components as a containers, so use `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. However, using `mapStateToProps` is not possible, because `store` is a root object, and we don't know what is the index of current sub-app in `appState`.

In future I plan separating these sub-apps and put then into own web-worker thread. In this case maybe it is ok to use multiple stores and send stores to the main thread and have it as a part of main store?

There are a lot of approaches how to handle this situation, basically, the problem is how to handle something like sub-applications with `redux` framework. Maybe some of you faced similar problem, or just know the solution how to solve in the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like in this case the best solution is to wrap each subApp with `<Provider>` and pass own store for each container. We can also use [react-redux-custom-store](https://github.com/emmenko/react-redux-custom-store) library to create stores with custom names.

**Update:**

Dan Abramov twitt: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/716217178731765762

Example:
https://gist.github.com/gaearon/eeee2f619620ab7b55673a4ee2bf8400

Comment: Well, it looks like Dan Abramov heard you and suggested a solution: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/716217178731765762

Comment: Yes, and the solution looks the same. I will add this link to my answer.

Comment: @CPHPython react-hot-loader has nothing to do with Redux and it won't help the OP in solving their specific issue

Comment: @ClementParis016 thanks for noticing, somehow that made sense to me before (modules VS sub-apps? Perhaps my comment was a complement to this solution? No idea now...). Anyway, hot-loader got deprecated, [fast-refresh](https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh) is the replacement and it was designed tor reloading modules (perhaps subapps had the same modules imports?). I can delete this comment as well for reducing entropy.

Answer (score 4):

Redux documentation now has information about this see

https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolatingsubapps

In a nutshell, you can treat these subapps as their own private apps with their own stores. They will be wrapped in the `<Provider>` HOC that is hooked into that specific store.

BigApp

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SubApp from './subapp'
​
class BigApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SubApp />
        <SubApp />
        <SubApp />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

SubApp

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducers'
import App from './App'
​
class SubApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = createStore(reducer)
  }
​
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a slightly different structure of global app state help you? For example:

```
const appState = {
    subApps: {
        subApp1: {},
        subApp2: {},
        // etc.
    },
    currentSubApp: 'subApp2',
};

const subApp2State = appState.subApps[appState.currentSubApp];
```

On the other hand, if your subApps are completely independent of the parent-app, you could let them use whatever structure they want (their own redux store for example, different from the one of the parent-app) and simply integrate them in React wrapper-components, like this:

```
import SubApp from '...anywhere...';

const SubAppWrapper = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.subApp = new SubApp({
            containerElement: this.refs.containerDiv,
            // other params
        });
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.subApp.destroy();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div ref="containerDiv"></div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: Agreed, all about simplifying state management by introducing child reducers

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible, because all the stacks are added dynamically. Data about stacks even can be loaded from database, so I don't know all the keys in advance.

Comment: Ok I see. But if you want to modify the state of each loaded subApp, you have to know in advance the structure of such state and the way to update it (the specific reducers), right? So maybe you could have the whole app state initialized with each potential subApp state type, and then activate a flag in a subApp type state when it is loaded

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't even know potential subApp types, sometimes, they can be created also dynamically (they will probably get some UID). I was thinking about few options:
- Multiple stores
- Do not use containers in subApps at all, use only props
- I've seen there is something like higher-order-store thing, but honestly, haven't investigated yet, couldn't not find proper docs about that.
- It it is possible <Provider> for multiple components, then I can map a proper store to each subApp. Then when I do `mapStateToProps(state)`, state could be a "local" state.

Comment: You don't need to be aware of the keys - this example exemplifies this http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html . This stores subreddit data, and it has no idea which subreddit you'll be visiting. It dynamically adds keys to the store.

Comment: Thank you! It is not a problem to store data, the problem is how to access needed data from container component. In the example above, subreddit data is stored and passed to the presentational component, what is not a problem. In my case I have a particular container and want to map needed properties.
`function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const subAppId = '?';
    return dataForSubApp: state.subApps[subAppId];
}
`
But I don't know a value of current "subAppId".
In all the examples I've found in the documentation, they use containers at the top, but I have some of them in the middle.

Comment: I just added an alternative solution, which allows your sub-apps to "live" in a completely independent way from the parent-app.